# Recommendation for a book for geographical distance calculations

Tags: distance, geodesy, great-circle, references

I am currently writing my Thesis and I need a book covering the geographical distance calculation like haversine and Vincenty. Since I am not of this field, I can't find books which might help me write. I am basically only interested in the calculations. I already have the original papers for the related stuff. But since I need some background and concept literature before I start with the calculation, I need a reference book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place to start is the [bibliography](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/geodesic-papers/biblio.html) provided by the [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) of Charles Karney.

This starts at the begining with:

> I. Newton, Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica (3rd edition,
>   Roy. Soc., 1726), Book 3, Prop. 19, Prob. 3, pp. 412–416.
>   https://books.google.com/books?id=0xYOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA412
>
> English
>   translation: Newton's Principia: The Mathematical Principles of
>   Natural Philosophy, by A. Motte (Adee, New York, 1848), pp. 405–409.
>   https://books.google.com/books?id=KaAIAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA405

and goes through to:

> G. Panou, The geodesic boundary value problem and its solution on a
>   triaxial ellipsoid, J. Geodetic Science 3(3), 240–249 (2013).
>   https://dx.doi.org/10.2478/jogs-2013-0028

Comment: Well thanks a lot. Although the list is quite comprehensive and useful, its a bit too much / too in-depth for  what I want. I would like basic concepts to write about in terms of literature review.

Comment: Try geosphere: https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/index.html refs in vignette

Comment: For basic concepts, see the 2 volumes of lecture notes by Rapp (1991 + 1993).  Links are given in the bibliography and repeated here http://kb.osu.edu/dspace/handle/1811/24333 http://kb.osu.edu/dspace/handle/1811/24409